# Fire onchange function when select the same option

Tags: javascript

I want this function to fire when users select both the first option or when they select the same option. I've tried onclick but it fires too quick.

```html
<div id=sources>
    Source1:
    <select id='source1'>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    Source2:
    <select id='source2'>
        <option value="honda">Honda</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
</div>
```

```js
var s1 = document.getElementById('source1'),
    s2 = document.getElementById('source2');

var select_sources = function () {
    var sourceX = s1.value,
        sourceY = s2.value;
    var constraints = {
        x: {
            optional: [{
                sourceId: sourceX
            }]
        },
        y: {
            optional: [{
                sourceId: sourceY
            }]
        }
    };
    init(constraints);
};

var init = function (sourceInfos) {
    console.log(sourceInfos);
};

s1.onchange = select_sources;
s2.onchange = select_sources;
```

Thank you,

Comment: Create a fiddle please

Comment: I think the codes are straightforward.

Comment: Your wording is a bit confusing. You want the event to fire when source1 Volvo is selected OR when source2 Volvo is selected?

Comment: I want the event to fire when both of them are selected in any event and I want it to fire again even if Volvo from source2 is already selected and re-selected it again. I mean every time when 2 sources are being selected altogether.